# Can one truncate page ranges in index using splitidx?

Tags: indexing

The following MWE

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{splitidx}
\makeindex
\newindex{idx}
\newindex{aut}    
\begin{document}    
\setcounter{page}{124}\index{Topic1|(}\index{Topic2|(}Text\newpage    
\setcounter{page}{126}\index{Topic1|)}Text\newpage    
\setcounter{page}{130}\index{Topic2|)}Text\newpage     
\printindex[idx][Subject Index]     
\end{document}
```

produces these index entries:

> Topic1, 124-126
>
> Topic2, 124-130

I would like to have:

> Topic1, 124-6
>
> Topic2, 124-30

Can this be done using splitidx?

From egreg's comment it seems to me I didn't ask a clear question.  I'm happy to have the same style for all indices.  What I'd like is a different format of the page range.  Instead of "124-126", I'd like the output to be "124-6", so the "12" from "126" is dropped.  Similarly, instead of "124-130", drop the "1" from "130", to get "124-30".

Comment: With `splitindex` you can apply only one index style to all indices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `splitindex` you can use only one index style for every index. This is not a problem if you use ranges only for an index or want that all indices share the same property.

The solution here uses `imakeidx`, because it's easier to specify different styles for the various indices and doesn't require running separately `splitindex` or `makeindex`.

I define an index style (using `filecontents*` to make the example self-contained); it encapsulates the page number(s) as argument to `\checkrange`. If `--` doesn't appear, the page number(s) are simply printed. Otherwise the check is performed.

If the number of digits differ, both numbers are printed (separated by `--`). Otherwise the first number is printed and digits are compared with the second number. Until the digits are the same, nothing is printed. Once a different digit is found, it and the remaining digits in the second number are printed.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{subjind.ist}
delim_0 ", \\checkrange{"
delim_t "}"
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{imakeidx}

\makeindex[title=Subject Index,options=-s subjind]

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\checkrange}{>{\SplitArgument{1}{--}}m}
 {
  \formatrange#1
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\formatrange}{mm}
 {
  \IfNoValueTF { #2 }
   { % no --, it's not a range
    #1
   }
   { % it's a range
    \egreg_range:nn { #1 } { #2 }
   }
 }

\bool_new:N \l__egreg_range_compare_bool

\cs_new_protected:Nn \egreg_range:nn
 {
  % print the start number
  #1--
  \int_compare:nNnTF { \str_count:n { #1 } } = { \str_count:n { #2 } }
   {% same number of digits, remove equal ones at the start
    \__egreg_range_compare:nn { #1 } { #2 }
   }
   {% different number of digits, print both
    #2
   }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__egreg_range_compare:nn
 {
  \bool_set_true:N \l__egreg_range_compare_bool
  % do a loop on the digits in the first number
  \int_step_inline:nn { \str_count:n { #1 } }
   {
    \bool_if:NTF \l__egreg_range_compare_bool
     {
      % if the digits coincide, print nothing
      \str_if_eq:eeF { \str_item:nn { #1 } { ##1 } } { \str_item:nn { #2 } { ##1 } }
       {
        \str_item:nn { #2 } { ##1 }
        % at the first differing digit, don't compare any longer
        \bool_set_false:N \l__egreg_range_compare_bool
       }
     }
     { \str_item:nn { #2 } { ##1 } }
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\setcounter{page}{95}\index{Topic0|(}Text\newpage
\setcounter{page}{101}\index{Topic0|)}Text\newpage
\setcounter{page}{124}\index{Topic1|(}\index{Topic2|(}Text\newpage
\setcounter{page}{126}\index{Topic1|)}Text\newpage
\setcounter{page}{134}\index{Topic2|)}Text\newpage
\printindex
\end{document}
```

[image]