# Page range truncation with imakeidx

Tags: indexing

This is a followup question to egreg's answer to [Can one truncate page ranges in index using splitidx?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/460037/can-one-truncate-page-ranges-in-index-using-splitidx) The answer runs into a problem if an index topic occurs in more than one page range. The following MWE, based on egreg's answer:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{subjind.ist}
delim_0 ", \\checkrange{"
delim_t "}"
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{imakeidx}

\makeindex[title=Subject Index,options=-s subjind]

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\checkrange}{>{\SplitArgument{1}{--}}m}
 {
  \formatrange#1
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\formatrange}{mm}
 {
  \IfNoValueTF { #2 }
   { % no --, it's not a range
    #1
   }
   { % it's a range
    \egreg_range:nn { #1 } { #2 }
   }
 }

\bool_new:N \l__egreg_range_compare_bool

\cs_new_protected:Nn \egreg_range:nn
 {
  % print the start number
  #1--
  \int_compare:nNnTF { \str_count:n { #1 } } = { \str_count:n { #2 } }
   {% same number of digits, remove equal ones at the start
    \__egreg_range_compare:nn { #1 } { #2 }
   }
   {% different number of digits, print both
    #2
   }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__egreg_range_compare:nn
 {
  \bool_set_true:N \l__egreg_range_compare_bool
  % do a loop on the digits in the first number
  \int_step_inline:nn { \str_count:n { #1 } }
   {
    \bool_if:NTF \l__egreg_range_compare_bool
     {
      % if the digits coincide, print nothing
      \str_if_eq:eeF { \str_item:nn { #1 } { ##1 } } { \str_item:nn { #2 } { ##1 } }
       {
        \str_item:nn { #2 } { ##1 }
        % at the first differing digit, don't compare any longer
        \bool_set_false:N \l__egreg_range_compare_bool
       }
     }
     { \str_item:nn { #2 } { ##1 } }
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\setcounter{page}{95}\index{Topic0|(}Text\newpage
\setcounter{page}{101}\index{Topic0|)}Text\newpage
\setcounter{page}{124}\index{Topic1|(}\index{Topic2|(}Text\newpage
\setcounter{page}{126}\index{Topic1|)}Text\newpage
\setcounter{page}{134}\index{Topic2|)}Text\newpage
\setcounter{page}{141}\index{Topic0}Text\newpage
\index{Topic0}Text\newpage
\index{Topic0}Text
\printindex
\end{document}
```

yields the following error message:

```
! LaTeX3 Error: Too many '--' tokens when trying to split argument.

For immediate help type H <return>.
 ...                                              

l.3   \item Topic0, \checkrange{95--101, 141--143}
```

Entering non-stop yields the following output:

[image]

which omits "-3" from the second index entry of Topic0. The question is how to get around this.

Edit following up on egreg's ingenious solution.  I don't know if I should ask a new follow up question, so I'm posing it first here in this edit.  egreg's solution doesn't seem to handle index sub-topics.  If one adds the following 4 lines

```
\setcounter{page}{135}\index{Topic0!sub0|(}Text\newpage
\setcounter{page}{136}\index{Topic0!sub0!subsub0|(}Text\newpage
\setcounter{page}{139}\index{Topic0!sub0!subsub0|)}Text\newpage
\setcounter{page}{140}\index{Topic0!sub0|)}Text\newpage
```

after

```
\setcounter{page}{134}\index{Topic2|)}Text\newpage
```

in the solution, one gets the following errors:

```
Output written in mwe.ind.
Transcript written in mwe.ilg.
 (mwe.ind
! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
l.4     \subitem sub0, 135--140}

? r
OK, entering \nonstopmode...
! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
l.5       \subsubitem subsub0, 136--139}

) [145] (mwe.aux) )
```

and this output:

[image]

Alas I don't understand egreg's code well enough to make the required changes.

Comment: Please don't pile up questions in questions. You started with *page ranges*, not mentioning other types of indexing and now subitems pop out. Without a full specification, it is impossible to guess what you really need.

Comment: @egreg: my apologies, when I originally asked the ranges question, I didn't think to specify that the index I'm writing had subitems.  Should I ask another question?  In any case your solutions are very helpful, it's just that I hadn't thought about the additional complications with subitems.

Comment: You have to add `delim_1 ", \\checkrange{"` and `delim_2 ", \\checkrange{"` to the `.ist` file.

Comment: I added the missing part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here it is:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{subjind.ist}
delim_0 ", \\checkrange{"
delim_1 ", \\checkrange{"
delim_2 ", \\checkrange{"
delim_t "}"
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{imakeidx}

\makeindex[title=Subject Index,options=-s subjind]

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\checkrange}{m}
 {
  \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l__ssind_in_seq { #1 }
  \seq_set_map:NNn \l__ssind_out_seq \l__ssind_in_seq { \checkrangeaux{##1} }
  \seq_use:Nn \l__ssind_out_seq {,~}
 }
\seq_new:N \l__ssind_in_seq
\seq_new:N \l__ssind_out_seq

\NewDocumentCommand{\checkrangeaux}{>{\SplitArgument{1}{--}}m}
 {
  \formatrange#1
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\formatrange}{mm}
 {
  \IfNoValueTF { #2 }
   { % no --, it's not a range
    #1
   }
   { % it's a range
    \egreg_range:nn { #1 } { #2 }
   }
 }

\bool_new:N \l__egreg_range_compare_bool

\cs_new_protected:Nn \egreg_range:nn
 {
  % print the start number
  #1--
  \int_compare:nNnTF { \str_count:n { #1 } } = { \str_count:n { #2 } }
   {% same number of digits, remove equal ones at the start
    \__egreg_range_compare:nn { #1 } { #2 }
   }
   {% different number of digits, print both
    #2
   }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__egreg_range_compare:nn
 {
  \bool_set_true:N \l__egreg_range_compare_bool
  % do a loop on the digits in the first number
  \int_step_inline:nn { \str_count:n { #1 } }
   {
    \bool_if:NTF \l__egreg_range_compare_bool
     {
      % if the digits coincide, print nothing
      \str_if_eq:eeF { \str_item:nn { #1 } { ##1 } } { \str_item:nn { #2 } { ##1 } }
       {
        \str_item:nn { #2 } { ##1 }
        % at the first differing digit, don't compare any longer
        \bool_set_false:N \l__egreg_range_compare_bool
       }
     }
     { \str_item:nn { #2 } { ##1 } }
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\setcounter{page}{95}\index{Topic0|(}Text\newpage
\setcounter{page}{101}\index{Topic0|)}Text\newpage
\setcounter{page}{124}\index{Topic1|(}\index{Topic2|(}Text\newpage
\setcounter{page}{126}\index{Topic1|)}Text\newpage
\setcounter{page}{134}\index{Topic2|)}Text\newpage
\setcounter{page}{135}\index{Topic0!sub0|(}Text\newpage
\setcounter{page}{136}\index{Topic0!sub0!subsub0|(}Text\newpage
\setcounter{page}{139}\index{Topic0!sub0!subsub0|)}Text\newpage
\setcounter{page}{140}\index{Topic0!sub0|)}Text\newpage
\setcounter{page}{141}\index{Topic0}Text\newpage
\index{Topic0}Text\newpage
\index{Topic0}Text
\printindex
\end{document}
```

Now `\checkrange` splits its input at commas and does the processing as before to every item. This also copes with subitems.

[image]

Comment: I'm trying to compile the MWE you've provided here (straight copy-paste) but I'm getting an Undefined control sequence error in l.3 of the .ind file...

In my own MWE where I borrowed your code (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/500636/page-range-truncation-in-index-with-memoir-class) it runs okay, but the page numbers aren't affected and still appear in the full range.

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: @Erika Such problems usually are due to not up-to-date TeX distribution

Comment: I've sorted that out, but the solution seems to break if there are any "see" or "see also" entries--can that be resolved (or should I ask a separate question?).

Comment: For the record, I ended up asking a separate question regarding this solution and "see (also)", here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/501382/truncated-minimal-page-range-in-index-with-see-also-references