# LaTeX index page range elision

Tags: indexing, imakeidx

I'm working on a book project using LaTeX and am stuck on a very fine point of style in the index. The publisher wants page ranges in the index to appear in the form `145--52` (rather than `145--152`), page range elision. I have no idea how to to get a LaTeX indexing package to do this. At the moment I'm using `imakeidx` and the project has two indices (Names and Subjects). I've put together a minimal working example. I'd be grateful for any advice,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{Index elision problem}
\date{July 2019}

\usepackage{imakeidx}

\makeindex[name = person,title=Name Index,columns=2]
\makeindex[name = subject,title=Subject Index,columns=2]

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\index[person]{Mr. T}
\index[subject]{vans}
\clearpage Space \clearpage filler \clearpage Space \clearpage filler \clearpage Space \clearpage filler \clearpage Space \clearpage filler \clearpage Space \clearpage 
Mr. T, vans
\index[person]{Mr. T|(}
\index[subject]{vans|(}
\clearpage filler \clearpage Space \clearpage filler \clearpage Space \clearpage filler
Mr. T, vans
\index[person]{Mr. T|)}
\index[subject]{vans|)}

\printindex[person]
\clearpage
\printindex[subject]

\end{document}
```

Comment: And what should it be for `61--69`??

Comment: 61—9. Just clip the digits that don’t add new information. 61—75 is fine.

Comment: I think there is already something like this on the site.

Comment: If you find it please let me know. I’ve been looking for a while.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/463434/4427 But tell your publisher that saving a few characters at the expense of clarity is a bit silly.

Comment: Thanks very much! I'll give this a try. Agreed.

Comment: Thanks again, your code worked for me. I *almost* regretted not using MS Word, but stayed strong.